# sql problema oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

buenas llevo días intentando resolver este ejercicio, tengo que hacerlo sobre oracle
11g, no consigo saber cuál es el error, el error que me da es 'ORA-00911: invalid character' esta es la sentencia:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFESORES(
    NIF VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50),
    APELLIDO1 VARCHAR(50),
    APELLIDO2 VARCHAR(50),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(150),
    TITULACION VARCHAR(50),
    SALARIO NUMBER(6,2),
    CONSTRAINT PROFESOR_FK PRIMARY KEY(NIF)
);

CREATE TABLE CURSOS(
    CODIGO VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    TOTAL_PLAZAS NUMBER(3),
    FECHA_INICIO DATE,
    FECHA_FINAL DATE,
    CONSTRAINT FECHA_CONSTRAINT CHECK(FECHA_INICIO < FECHA_FINAL),
    TOTAL-HORAS NUMBER(3),
    PROFESOR VARCHAR(10), 
    CONSTRAINT CURSO_FK PRIMARY KEY(CODIGO),
    CONSTRAINT PROFESOR_FK FOREIGM KEY(PROFESOR) REFERENCES PROFESORES(NIF)
);

CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS(
    NIF VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50),
    APELLIDO1 VARCHAR(50),
    APELLIDO2 VARCHAR(50),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(150),
    SEXO CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT SEXO_CONSTRAINT CHECK(SEXO ='F' OR SEXO='M'),
    CURSO VARCHAR(10),
     CONSTRAINT ALUMNO_FK PRIMARY KEY(NIF),
    CONSTRAINT CURSO_FK FOREIGM KEY(CURSO) REFERENCES CURSOS(CODIGO)
);
```

muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: al primero le faltaba una coma pero, la primera tabla esta bien la segunda me da fallo de caracter

Comment: ¿Tenés la certeza de que las palabras clave están bien escritas?

Comment: muy buenas, esta solucionado, parte de que habia varios errores en el codigo "Oracle 11g no me deja escribir todas las tablas a la vez he tenido que crearlas una a una"

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando un guion medio en la columna `TOTAL-HORAS`. En el código que compartiste como respuesta lo cambiaste por un guion bajo y por eso ya no te marcó error.

Answer (score 0):

al final pude arreglarlo, ademas de que oracle 11g no me dejaba crear todas las tablas de golpe tuve que ir una a una. tambien habia varios fallos, aqui dejo el codigo funcional

```
CREATE TABLE PROFESORES (
    NIF VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50),
    APELLIDO1 VARCHAR2(50),
    APELLIDO2 VARCHAR2(50),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR2(150),
    TITULACION VARCHAR2(50),
    SALARIO NUMBER(6, 2),
    CONSTRAINT PROFESOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (NIF)
);

CREATE TABLE CURSOS (
    CODIGO VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE,
    TOTAL_PLAZAS NUMBER(3),
    FECHA_INICIO DATE,
    FECHA_FINAL DATE,
    CONSTRAINT FECHA_CONSTRAINT CHECK (FECHA_INICIO < FECHA_FINAL),
    TOTAL_HORAS NUMBER(3),
    PROFESOR VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT CURSO_PK PRIMARY KEY (CODIGO),
    CONSTRAINT PROFESOR_FK FOREIGN KEY (PROFESOR) REFERENCES PROFESORES (NIF)
);
CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS (
    NIF VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50),
    APELLIDO1 VARCHAR2(50),
    APELLIDO2 VARCHAR2(50),
    DIRECCION VARCHAR2(150),
    SEXO CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT SEXO_CONSTRAINT CHECK (SEXO IN ('F', 'M')),
    CURSO VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT ALUMNO_PK PRIMARY KEY (NIF),
    CONSTRAINT CURSO_FK FOREIGN KEY (CURSO) REFERENCES CURSOS (CODIGO)
);
```

muchas gracias por la ayuda compañero

Comment: No se recomienda usar para llaves primarias el tipo de dato VARCHAR2.
Es mejor que utilice para cada una de las 3 tablas una llave primaria numérica (tipo NUMBER) a partir de una secuencia, y que más bien las columnas NIF (que supongo es algún tipo de identificación, ¿qué se usa en cuál país y qué significa?) les cree un índice unitario, esto además permite que si se guardó erradamente ese valor NIF se pueda actualizar sin afectar la relación maestro-detalle de las demás tablas. ¿ese valor NIF tiene letras y números?